# iframe how to use parent javascript file in iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I am having two html file Parent.html & Child.html.
Parent.html imports jquery.js file and Child.html in iframe.

Parent.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$('body').click(function() {
 alert("asdgaskdj");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!--Parent do  some thing-->
<iframe id="workspace"  style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:auto;" src="Child.html">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Child.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script>
$('body').click(function() {
 alert("asdgaskdj");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!--child do some thing-->
</body>
</html>
```

My qustion is already jquery has been imported by Parent.html
Should i import it again in Child.html

if i dont import in Child.html it shows $ is undefined.

Parent.html already imported 255KB of js file.
Child.html also want to do the same.
If it does then again 255kb of file has to be downloaded from the server.
Is any other way to reach the solution.

Plz HELP !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to include it twice, but the server will cache it. So the client is downloading 255KB the first time, and remembers it has downloaded the document already, so it won't download it a second time.

Also see the [w3c specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html) and this [tutorial](http://www.garron.me/en/bits/apache-htaccess-add-cache-control-header-file-type.html). You would have to add the following lines (for example) to your .htaccess to enable caching (it's enabled by default by the most webhosters):

```
 # Cache all your static assets for 1 month
 <filesMatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
 </filesMatch>
```

Additionally you can enable gzip-compression, which will minimize the traffic even more. It's described in [this tutorial](http://salscode.com/tutorials/2009/10/15/gzip-htaccess/).

Answer (score 1):

The bad news: You need to have the jQuery library loaded in each frame that requires it.

The good news: The browser will know that it has already requested it, and so simply use its cached copy instead of loading it anew.

There are further improvements you can make, too:

- If you ensure that you are using a minified version of jQuery, it will bring your download size down significantly - 1.10.2 goes from 97KB to 38KB.
- If you enable gzip compression, then the file is compressed during download, which saves additional bandwidth.
- If you use a CDN (such as Google), you may benefit from the user already having a cached copy of jQuery that another site referenced. As a result, they wouldn't need to download it at all - it would already be there.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to include the jQuery plugin again in child.html.

Just insert `window.parent` before `$` to access parent jQuery plugin.

**Child.html**

```
<script>
  window.parent.$('body').click(function(){
      alert("asdgaskdj");
  });
</script>
```